# GeoServer SLD points styling

Tags: geoserver, sld

I have a layer of Points with some attributes in GeoServer. Is it possible to create a style that would combine all the points in this layer in a line according to "date" attribute order? I want to receive a list of points through WFS service and single line through WMS service from the same  layer.

EDIT: I use PostgreSQL with PostGIS.

Comment: What's your data source?

Comment: @DPSSpatial I use PostgreSQL database with PostGIS

Comment: the answer below was what I was going to suggest...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. SLD cannot do this.

But you can create SQL Views from GeoServer:

Go to Layer -> New Layer -> Choose your PostGIS Store from the Dropdown -> Configure new SQL view ...

Then you can write something like this using [ST_MakeLine](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_MakeLine.html) as SQL statement:

```
SELECT ST_MakeLine(the_geom ORDER BY date) as line FROM your_points_table;
```

For the WFS Service you will receive the same line of course. But you could split the line to points from the WFS in your client afterwards.

Comment: Idea should work but that SQL for sure not. See better examples in http://postgis.net/docs/ST_MakeLine.html.

Comment: right, the points need to be ordered, not the line ;-) Updated the answer